# Consulta para convertir minutos a horas en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola chicos ¿se puede convertir minutos a horas en una consulta de mysql? les explico mi problema, quiero obtener la hora de terminación de un turno, en mi tabla tengo los campos **in_time** y **duration** pero el campo de duration esta en minutos, entonces tengo la idea de convertir el campo duration en horas y después sumarle eso a la hora de entrada (in_time) y así obtener la hora de terminación del turno, inserto en una imagen lo que quiero obtener:
[image: resultado que quiero]

y esto es la información que tengo en la tabla, como se observa el campo de duration esta en minutos, por ejemplo si nos enfocamos en turno Vespertino Oficinas vemos que inicia a las 12:50 y la duración del turno es de 480 minutos que traducido a horas son 8hrs, la solución que tengo en mente es que a la hora 12:50 sumarle las 8:00 de duración y así obtener la hora de salida que serían 20:50, quiero obtener eso mediante una consulta mysql ¿es esto posible? o ¿tienen una mejor idea? :c agradezco su atención y espero puedan orientarme.

```
select id, alias, in_time, duration as 'end_time' from att_timeinterval;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es `in_time`?. Por favor, el código en formato texto. El código en la imagen no se puede copiar y pegar para editar. Si puedes subir la definición de tu tabla (DDL),  mucho mejor. Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras el campo int_time es de tipo time(6) ya puse la consulta en formato de texto

Comment: Si puedes te recomiendo que normalices tu modelo de datos. Es un error declarar una columna del tipo `time`, habría sido mejor declararla del tipo  `DateTime`. Si por cualquier motivo (Covid-19 por poner un ejemplo) la situación evoluciona y hay turnos que empiecen un día y terminen otro (un turno entre las 23:00 horas  del día anterior y las 05:00 horas del día siguiente por ejemplo), tu modelo de datos se viene abajo. Además, mediante columnas `DateTime` es más simple obtener el intervalo de tiempo transcurrido entre dos valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la forma de hacerlo, guiándome de lo que me dijo @Alberto, de la siguiente manera:

select id, alias, in_time, duration, addtime((floor(duration/60)x10000 + (duration%60x100)), time(att_timeinterval.in_time))as 'end_time' FROM att_timeinterval;

por si alguien se encuentra en la misma situación, gracias por su apoyo compañeros.

Answer (score 2):

No me queda muy claro lo que deseas hacer, pero estoy de acuerdo con A. Cedano sobre la normalización, sin embargo esto podría servirte, siempre y cuando duration sea un entero (seria bueno saber que tipo de dato es duration)

select id, alias, in_time, duration as 'end_time' from att_timeinterval;

select id, alias, in_time, **TIME(SUM(FLOOR(duration /60)*10000)+ (duration%60*100) + time(in_time))** as 'end_time' from att_timeinterval;

FLOOR(duration /60): toma el valor numérico en minutos ej.:530 y lo divide entre 60 para obtener el numero de horas enteras que sería igual a 8.

(FLOOR(duration /60)*10000): se multiplica por 10000 para cubrir los espacios vacíos en en el formato hh:mm:ss. seria algo así 80000

(duration%60*100): te permite obtner el equivalente en minutos de las horas incompeltas para este ejemplo 50 y se multiplica por 100 para cubrir este formato mm:ss, se vería así 5000

SUM(): realizamos la suma de 080000 + 5000 + in_time

en tu ejemplo si in_time vale 12:00:00

la sumatorias quedaría de la siguiente forma 080000 + 5000 + 120000 = 205000

El primer TIME() se encarga de convertir este valor 205000 en 20:50:00

espero te sirva saludos

Comment: Hola @alberto tu comentario me ayudó a estructurar mi consulta, pero tengo algunos detalles con unos turnos en específico, por ejemplo tengo tres turnos que empiezan a las 08:50:00 el primero tiene una duración de 630 min, el segundo de 450min y el tercero de 370min pero al momento de hacer la operación que mencionas me arroja un resultado nulo, justo en esos tres turnos ¿tienes alguna idea del porqué? UnU